# Is there any way on MySQL to update and select the updated rows in a single statement t?

Tags: mysql, select, join

Can I join SELECT and UPDATE statement? If yes, how can I do that?

I have table which name is ***news***.

I show news on my website. If someone read news I add **1** to **hit**. I do that with 2 queries:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=2 LIMIT 1");
mysql_query("UPDATE news SET hit=hit+1 WHERE id=2");
```

But I want to join them.

```
id | title     | content           |hit
---+-----------+-------------------+---
1  | sdfsdfdsf | dfsdffdsfds836173 |5
2  | sfsdfds   | sdfsdsdfdsfdsfsd4 |9
3  | ssdfsdfds | sdfdsfs           |3
```

**Update:** the OP wants to update and select the updated rows within one sql statement.

Comment: you can do it in a stored procedure

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to UPDATE values in one table with data from another table?

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of what do you really want sothat we can help you

Comment: ... Make sure to include complete, concise [sample code](http://sscce.org/) when you edit your question to clarify it. For SQL questions, this means table schema (`CREATE TABLE` statements), sample data (`INSERT` statements), as much of the queries as you've been able to work out and the desired results for the sample data.

Comment: In Postgres this would be a simple `UPDATE ... RETURNING *` but I don't think MySQL has anything comparable to that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a stored procedure:

```
delimiter //;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ReadNews//;
CREATE PROCEDURE ReadNews(IN newsId INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=newsId LIMIT 1;
    UPDATE news SET hit=hit+1 WHERE id=newsId;
END
```

Usage:

```
CALL ReadNews(2)
```

**Update**

By the way, most mysql clients support multiple actions in a single statement.
A common use for this is (Pseude C# Code)

```
var result = DB.Execute("INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (1, 'test'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
```

which will perform an Insert and Return the id of the newly created record.

You possibly could do

```
var result = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET hit=hit+1 WHERE id=2; SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Any numeric field will do it by this (tinyint, int, float, etc).

```
mysql_query("UPDATE news SET hit=hit+1 WHERE id=2 ");
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

best way is to write trigger which will increment hit count on select news
When SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=2 LIMIT 1 Fire trigger UPDATE news SET hit=hit+1 WHERE id=2